# How can a cypher query be written to create hyperedges?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with offers and customers. A customer can share an offer with another customer, so when this happens, I create a hyperedge.

(CustomerA)-[:SHARED_OFFER]->(newNode)

(newNode)-[:FOR_OFFER]->(offer)

(newNode)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(customers) (this can be many customers)

Now if another customer B shares the same offer with others, I would want a new node created to represent this relationship. 
Is there a way to accomplish all this in one Cypher query?

I am using:

```
start c=node:node_auto_index(name="C1"), o=node:node_auto_index(name="Offer"), sharedCustomer=node:node_auto_index(name="C2")
create unique c-[:SHARED_OFFER]->(sharedOffer)-[:FOR_OFFER]->(o), (sharedOffer)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(sharedCustomer)
```

which works for the first time. See the console at: http://console.neo4j.org/r/76no2g
This query correctly created relationships when C1 shared Offer with C2.

Executing the query for the case when C2 now shares Offer with C3 causes the same node to be reused---that's not what I want. There should be a new node created from C2 with the SHARED_OFFER relationship. Here is the query:

```
start c=node:node_auto_index(name="C2"), o=node:node_auto_index(name="Offer"), sharedCustomer=node:node_auto_index(name="C3")
create unique c-[:SHARED_OFFER]->(sharedOffer)-[:FOR_OFFER]->(o), (sharedOffer)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(sharedCustomer)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Note: I'm using 1.8.1 REST, so trying to accomplish this all in one go rather than in parts.

Comment: Just for reference, I think it's useful to leave a pointer to [this other similar question about hyperedges in Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20877582/4756173).

Answer (score 1):

simply don't use `create unique` but just `create`. but remember to first specify all nodes you got in the path in the start clause and leave the param `sharedOffer` always unspecified so the create command will create just the unspecified elements.

**update** use `create` instead of `create unique` and filter on existing relations (or use 2 queries - one to check whether an sharedOffer already exists with C1 and second to update sharedOffer with C3):

```
START c=node:node_auto_index(name="C1"), o=node:node_auto_index(name="Offer"), sharedCustomer=node:node_auto_index(name="C2")
WHERE not(c-[:SHARED_OFFER]->(sharedOffer)-[:FOR_OFFER]->(o))
CREATE c-[:SHARED_OFFER]->(sharedOffer)-[:FOR_OFFER]->(o), (sharedOffer)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(sharedCustomer)
```

Comment: If I use just create, then C2 sharing with C3 works as expected. But execute the same create with now C1 and C3---and a new shared offer node is created instead of re-using the one from the first C1->C2 share. That's why I landed up with unique :-) Also--can you clarify what you meant by leaving sharedOffer unspecified?

Comment: I had not tried the filter- it is an interesting idea. The above query satisfies some cases but unfortunately not all. Like if C1 already has shared O1 with a C2, then C1 sharing O1 with C3 should reuse the existing shared offer and just create the shared offer to C3 node. Trying to satisfy all these in one query has been difficult hence posted it here. Will try with some filters else keep it broken into two queries. Thanks.