# Is there any way to create a hypergraph in neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j

Is there any way to create a hypergraph in neo4j? Or any other db tool for this issue?

Comment: "a hypergraph is a generalization of a graph in which an edge can connect any number of vertices". How can we make this in neo4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example for a hypergraph datastructure in the ["Graph Databases" book](http://graphdatabases.com) (the email chapter example).

And another one in the [neo4j manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html).

Comment: The Neo4j Manual link provided (Jan 2014) is broken, but appears to be this one (Mar 2018) based on the last part of the original URL: http://fooo.fr/~vjeux/github/github-recommandation/db/doc/manual/html/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to add an extra node that represents the subgraph, and connect that to all of the subgraph, and then relate to it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2023, Neo4j doesn't support *hyperedges*. The typical way around this would be to create an **Intermediate Node**. This can help deduplicate repeated data as well.

This concept is taught on the lesson [Neo4j Graph Data Modeling Course - Adding Intermediate Nodes](https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/modeling-fundamentals/8-adding-intermediate-nodes/1-intermediate-nodes/).

I wish they had support for creating this type of thing through Cypher, I mean Neo4j handling the intermediate nodes creation while we see hyperedges from the outside, but that doesn't seem to be the case, yet.